# rename dll file while making build in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, linker

Am working on VC++ application that generates an exe file and dll file with same name.

Now i want to change the dll filename for purpose.

I tried it changing in Project-Properties but still no luck.

Application is giving the renamed dll while  i build.

But if i run the exe it showing the error "The Program cant start, dll name is missing"

Please tell me how to generate the dll with a different name.

Comment: Have you tried the Target Name property?

Comment: yes i did, application is giving the renamed dll while  i build. But if i run the exe it showing the error "The Program cant start, dll name is missing"

Answer (score 1):

A DLL must be in the path of the executable, so first check if your path is setup correctly or copy the DLL into the directory where your EXE is.

If you link against a DLL, the name of the DLL may not change, as it will be used for reference. If you want to be able to rename the DLL as you whish you must either load the DLL dynamically, then you can load a DLL from wherever you want. Or you must link against the renamed DLL.